# Is there a way to wait for THREE.TextureLoader.load() to finish?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working with release R73.
My current task is to fill an array with materials. The content of this array is supposed to be used later. That usage depends on all materials to me completely loaded.

By now I loop through an array of JSON information and call this code for every element:

```
TLoader.load(
        BASE_ODB_URL + jsonMat.pic,
        function (texture) {
            texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            texture.repeat.set(jsonMat.scaleu, jsonMat.scalev);
            Mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                    map : texture,
                    side : THREE.DoubleSide,
                    name : jsonMat.mname
                });
            THREEMatList.push(Mat);
        },
        function (xhr) {
        }, //onProgress
            function (xhr) {
            Mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                    color : 0xff0000,
                    side : THREE.DoubleSide,
                    name : jsonMat.mname
                });
            THREEMatList.push(Mat);
        } 
    )
```

TLoader is initialized earlier: var TLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

If a material isn't there, when it is needed, I get a fallback material. This was only intended as an error option.
Is there a way to wait until .load() finishes?

Comment: Is skipping the actual rendering (instead of using a fallback material) until your material list is fully populated an option?

Comment: the `function (texture) {` is called only when the texture has been loaded.

Comment: Why not first fill out an array of "fallback" materials, as in the case of a successful download them to replace them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to solve this is through [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)'s as they are really the way forward and I personally think it's a shame `TextureLoader` doesn't return a `Promise` to start with (it would make this a little bit easier). However, do keep in mind that IE11 will need a polyfill as it lacks native support for promises.

Something like this should do it, where `textureArray` represents your JSON data in an iterable `Array`:

```
var allPromises = [];

textureArray.forEach( function( jsonMat ) {

    allPromises.push( new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {

        TLoader.load(
           BASE_ODB_URL + jsonMat.pic,

           function( texture ) {
               // Success callback of TextureLoader
               texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
               texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
               texture.repeat.set( jsonMat.scaleu, jsonMat.scalev );
               var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                   map: texture,
                   side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                   name: jsonMat.mname
               });
               THREEMatList.push( material );

               // We're done, so tell the promise it is complete
               resolve( material );
           },

           function( xhr ) {
               // Progress callback of TextureLoader
               // ...
           },

           function( xhr ) {
               // Failure callback of TextureLoader
               // Reject the promise with the failure
               reject( new Error( 'Could not load ' + jsonMat.pic ) );
           }
        );

    }));

});

Promise.all( allPromises )
    .then( function( arrayOfMaterials ) {
        // All textures are now loaded, and this array
        // contains all the materials that you created
    }, function( error ) {
        console.error( "Could not load all textures:", error );
    });
```

So what's happening here is that one overarching `Promise` is used to keep track of the status of the other `Promise`s. Each texture being loaded is wrapped in a `Promise`, which are added to `allPromises`. Finally that entire set of promises is tested for success or failure, and at that point you know about the overall success or failure.

One important thing to keep in mind here is that the `Promise.all` will only succeed if *all* the textures were loaded, and it will fail as soon as any one fails. If you need finer control than that you'll need a `Promise` polyfill with more features than the Promise/A+ spec offers, such as [RSVP.js](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js). Or instead of `reject()`ing the promise you could `resolve()` it and handle the result gracefully.

Answer (score 5):

Threejs already provides a callback for all elements loaded - via the use of a [LoadingManager](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/managers/LoadingManager). By default, TextureLoader uses the DefaultLoadingManager:

```
import {TextureLoader, DefaultLoadingManager} from './three.module.js';

const getTextures = ()=> new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  const loader = new TextureLoader();
  DefaultLoadingManager.onLoad = ()=>resolve(textures);
  const textures = [
    "image1.jpg",
    "image2.jpg",
    "image3.jpg"
  ].map(filename=>loader.load(filename));
});

getTextures().then(result=>console.log("We received,", result,"!"));
```

That's going to wait for *all* assets to load, though. If you want to be listening for a specific subset of assets loaded, you can do that by constructing a custom LoadingManager and passing it into your TextureLoader to manage different asset bundles separately:

```
import {TextureLoader, LoadingManager} from './three.module.js';

const getTextures = ()=> new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  const manager = new LoadingManager(()=>resolve(textures));
  const loader = new TextureLoader(manager);
  const textures = [
    "image1.jpg",
    "image2.jpg",
    "image3.jpg"
  ].map(filename=>loader.load(filename));
});

getTextures().then(result=>console.log("We received,", result,"!"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this simple helper if you need to load multiple textures before rendering your scene :

```
    /**
     *
     * @param {Array} texturesSources - List of Strings that represent texture sources
     * @returns {Array} Array containing a Promise for each source 
     */
    function getTextures (texturesSources) {
        const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
        return texturesSources.map(textureSource => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                loader.load(
                    textureSource,
                    texture => resolve(texture),
                    undefined, // onProgress callback not supported from r84
                    err => reject(err)
                )
            })
        })
    }
```

Then wrap your code using `Promise.all`, allowing to fetch the sources in parallel, and fail properly by catching the error.

Example :

```
const texturesBasePath = '../assets/textures/'
const texturesSRC = [
    'image1.jpg',
    'image2.jpg',
    'image3.jpg',
].map(texture => texturesBasePath + texture)

Promise.all(getTextures(texturesSRC))
    .then(textures => {
        // create your materials, meshs...
        // render the scene
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Comment: Hey that's a great answer - but I have a question: is there a way to ENUMERATE the Textures that come back from the Promises? So that they match up with the order of the URL's in the `texturesSRC` array upon which you call `.map`? I'm asking because I'm thinking it's possible that some Textures/images might be smaller than others, so they might load and return more quickly then ones that went out before them - you know what I mean? Or is that just not how Promises work? Do they always return in the order they were sent?

Comment: @Sirab33 you still can loop on `textures` parameter that is passed as a parameter of the callback called once all promises are settled (when `then` is called). So by using `Promise.all()`, the `then()` function will be called when all of the textures promises have resolved. And to answer to you last question, yes, the order of elements contained in the array passed to `Promise.all(array)` is preserved.