# preloading multiple textures in with Three.js THREE.textureLoader

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, three.js, promise

In another post I had a few issues with loading textures, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35540880/three-textureloader-is-not-loading-images-files). Now I have taken the advice as per the links provided form there, and as per the [documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/TextureLoader), I have come up with this solution.

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = '';

var fileArray = [   
                {name : 'texture1' , url : '...jpg'},
                {name :'texture2', url : '...jpg'},
                {name : 'texture3' ,url : '...jpg'},
                {name :'texture4', url : '....jpg'},
                {name :'texture5', url : '...jpg'},
                {name :'texture6', url : '...jpg'},
                {name :'texture7', url : '...jpg'},
                {name :'texture8', url : '...jpg'},
                {name :'texture9', url : '...jpg'}
                ];

function loadTextures( callback ) {

    var promiseArray = [],
        path = './textures/';

    fileArray.forEach( function ( fileOBJ ) {

       promiseArray.push ( new Promise( function ( resolve , reject ) {

            loader.load(

                path+fileOBJ.url ,

                function ( texture ) {

                    var modelOBJ = new Object();

                    modelOBJ[fileOBJ.name] = texture;

                    if( modelOBJ[fileOBJ.name] instanceof THREE.Texture ) resolve( modelOBJ )

                },

                function ( xhr ) {

                    console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

                },

                function ( xhr ) {

                    reject( new Error ( xhr + 'An error occurred loading while loading' + fileOBJ.url ) )

                }
            ) 

    } ) );

} )

Promise.all( promiseArray )

  .then( 

      function ( textures ) {

        for( var i in textures ) {

           var key = Object.keys( textures[i] ) 

           /* all textures are still undefined! */
           console.log( textures[key] )

        }

          if( callback && typeof( callback ) === "function" && fileArray.length == textures.length ) callback( textures )

      },

      function ( error ) {

            callback( error )

      } )
}
```

What I plan on doing with the object array I have in the callback is to pass it into another function in which I create create all the Meshes I will be using in my scene. However, the textures are still 'undefined' when then are passed to my other function. I want to know why this is still happening. I am using Three.js 74.

Comment: I expect you can more easily achieve what you want by using `THREE.LoadingManager`. See it used in http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html.

Comment: I was originally having problems with asynchronously loading all the textures. When creating the scene nothing would show up. The issue was addressed below. I will take a better look at the loading manager documentation and example, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are coming up undefined because you're treating the `textures` data coming out of `Promise.all` as an object; `Promise.all` produces an array. Try iterating through `textures` as an array. You can always post-process in your callbacks, putting the textures back into an object with keys for the sake of the next function in your program.

```
Promise.all( promiseArray )
   .then( function ( textures ) {

       // sanity check as an array:
       for( var i = 0; i < textures.length; i++ ) {
           console.log( textures[i] )
       }

       // or as an alternate sanity check:
       console.log( textures );

       // then do some post-processing to put your textures back into an object with keys
    }
    // error handling here...
```

Here is the MDN reference for [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: @LambShank - no worries! I just spent the past few weeks learning Promises and how to use them in my Three.js work. It's thorny stuff! Best wishes.