# Dynamically texture change not work in three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I try to change texture/image dynamically in three js.

i got below error

THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture has been deprecated. Use THREE.TextureLoader() instead.

below my code

```
 src="http://localhost/3d_view/textures/wall/wall6.jpg";
 mesh1.material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(src);
 mesh1.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

I am doing wrong, Anyone please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Three.TextureLoader is not loading images files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35540880/three-textureloader-is-not-loading-images-files)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try with following...

```
var image = new Image();

image.src = "....../xyz.png";

$(image).load(function() {
    // ...
   var _tempMap = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(getBase64Image(image));

   mesh1.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: _tempMap, overdraw:0.5}); //Your desire material you can use.
});


function getBase64Image(img) {
     // Create an empty canvas element
     var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
     canvas.width = img.width;
     canvas.height = img.height;

     // Copy the image contents to the canvas
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

     // Get the data-URL formatted image
     // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to
     // guess the original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg"
     // will re-encode the image.
     var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

   return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

Comment: You're adding a lot of overhead here, overhead which is only useful if you need to make changes to the texture programmatically.

Comment: Yes actually i did this for one of my previous project. I only suggested this could help that's it.