# THREE.js Add textures with Promises

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I'm trying to use promises to load textures in `THREE.JS` but i don't know how to do it. I've seen how they work, but is there any example?
I'm trying to load an pic (`img.png`) in a cube mesh.

I don't want to use JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to wait for THREE.TextureLoader.load() to finish?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283386/is-there-a-way-to-wait-for-three-textureloader-load-to-finish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the source code of ***THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture*** from THREE.js:

```
THREE.ImageUtils = {

  crossOrigin: undefined,

  loadTexture: function ( url, mapping, onLoad, onError ) {

    var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();
    loader.crossOrigin = this.crossOrigin;

    var texture = new THREE.Texture( undefined, mapping );

    loader.load( url, function ( image ) {

      texture.image = image;
      texture.needsUpdate = true;

      if ( onLoad ) onLoad( texture );

    }, undefined, function ( event ) {

      if ( onError ) onError( event );

    } );

    texture.sourceFile = url;

    return texture;

  },
```

So you can just wrap that up in a custom function that returns a Promise (this is ES6 syntax):

```
loadTextureAsync (url, mapping) {

  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {

    const onLoad = (texture) => resolve (texture)

    const onError = (event) => reject (event)

    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
      url, mapping, onLoad, onError)
  })
}
```

Comment: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture has been deprecated. Use THREE.TextureLoader() instead.

Check out my reply below for an alternative solution

Answer (score 2):

I use `THREE.TextureLoader` and wrapping it in a Promise like this:

```
// Wrapper function that returns a Promise that resolves to a texture instance
function loadTexture(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    new THREE.TextureLoader().load(url, resolve)
  })
}

// How to use it
loadTexture('myTexture.jpg').then(texture => {
  var geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(500, 60, 40)
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture })
  sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
  scene.add(sphere)
})
```