# Loading three.js texture in react as base64 string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, render-to-texture

I'm using server to generate base64 string representation of charts. Then load it to react component by fetching data with POST request. Data loads to react state but scene renders before texture is loaded. I've read [Is there a way to wait for THREE.TextureLoader.load() to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283386/is-there-a-way-to-wait-for-three-textureloader-load-to-finish/33292152#33292152) , should I also use `promise` ? I would like to communicate with use of react state, because final communication is going to be more complicated then in below example.

```
const Comp= () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(null)

    // basic three.js scene setting
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(28, 1, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(75, 25, 50);

    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    scene.add(camera);
    camera.add(new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, Infinity));

    var cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(3,3, 0.0001);

    // fetching data
    const getFile = (event) => {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/getFile',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                method: 'POST'
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => setState(response.state))
    }
    
    // fetch data when loading
    useEffect(
        () => getFile(), []
    )

    // use effect when change of state happens
    // (it depends on [state])
    useEffect(
        () => {
            // state contains image data as string representation of base64 
            var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("data:image/jpeg;base64," + state);
            var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });

            var cubes = []
            const n = 100;
            const V = 111;
    
            // rest is irrelevant
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, mat);

                cubes[i] = mesh
                var x = V * (Math.random() - .5);
                var y = V * (Math.random() - .5);
                var z = V * (Math.random() - .5);
                var r = Math.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2) / 20
                x /= r
                y /= r
                z /= r
                // console.log(r, x,y,z)
                cubes[i].position.x = x;
                cubes[i].position.y = y;
                cubes[i].position.z = z;
                scene.add(cubes[i]);
            }
        }, [state])

        return (
            <p ref={() => animate()} />
        )
}

export default Comp;
```

Answer (score 3):

[`TextureLoader.load`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=textureloa#api/en/loaders/TextureLoader.load) uses callbacks for `onLoad`, `onError`, and `onProgress`.

So if you want to make the scene wait until the texture is loaded, don't start rendering until `onLoad` or `onError` is called.

Example:

```js
let url = "...";
let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

function onLoad(tex){
  // start rendering now
}

function onError(){
  // start rendering now?
}

function onProgress(xhr){
  //...
}

loader.load(url, onLoad, onError, onProgress);
```

In recent versions of three.js, there is also a [`loadAsync`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=Loader#api/en/loaders/Loader.loadAsync) function, which returns a `Promise`. With this, you can construct your application to leverage `async`/`await` to wait for the texture to finish loading.

Pseudo-code:

```js
// set up your scene, etc., then...

async function run(){
  let url = "...";
  let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

  function onProgress(xhr){
    //...
  }

  await loader.loadAsync(url, onProgress); // or use .then/.catch

  // start rendering now
}

run();
```

Three.js r127

Comment: it does not work, I dont pass URL but data throught the state to `loader.load`, data: `"data:image/jpeg;base64," + state`

Comment: judging by the docs of [TextureLoader.load](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=image#api/en/loaders/TextureLoader.load), it should works as it says "url — the path or URL to the file. This can also be a Data URI." Thought the progress event may not work as it also says "Please note three.js r84 dropped support for TextureLoader progress events." I'm not sure how up to date the docs are though.

Comment: Failing that, you could always just create the image element and attach an onload listener to create and update the texture as I have done in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/p03wfrw4/)

Comment: Looks like the docs are behind, then. But yes, a b64 data URL is still a URL, and will still work with `TextureLoader`.

Answer (score 2):

I know is not the proper answer but you should take a look to R3F React-three-fiber

https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber

and it has useLoader on its api:

https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/blob/master/markdown/api.md#useloader

where you'll be able to do:

useLoader(loader: THREE.Loader, url: string , extensions?, xhr?)